# iOS Backup: Restore single program's settings?

Tags: ios, backup, restore

I have an iPod Touch and an iPhone. Both have the same certain application installed, but I want to transfer the Touch's app settings to the iPhone's app.

I already downloaded the iPhone Backup Extractor which lets me look into the backup. All human readable.

Is it possible to inject this part of the Touch's backup into the iPhone's backup and then sync it?

Comment: See this answer for more information how to get into backups... http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/i-want-to-restore-iphone-data-that-didnt-get-restored-a-few-weeks-ago-but-don

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, it is possible to replace parts of the backup package, but in practice, I have no real success with that plan. Often the format iTunes uses to store the data changes with versions of iTunes and editing files under a database's nose can lead to corruption.

It's easier for me to connect both devices and quit the program to make sure it's a clean boot when you resume the app. Then I use [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) to read the preferences from the app bundle on the correct device and replace that folder on the bad device. This way if things crash, you still have pristine backups in iTunes to restore things.